# Remove truncate styles from an element

Tags: html, css

I have a text that needs to be truncated (h4 tag) and another one ("a" tag) which must not be truncated but always displayed on the same line with the h4 text. I've tried to include the h4 tag into div and add on that div the styles for truncating the text, but this way the link will be displayed under the h4 text.

So, the problem is that I need h4 text to be truncated and the link to not be truncated but displayed on the same line.

CSS:

```
.thread-title {
   width: 100px;
   white-space: nowrap;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   overflow: hidden;   
} 
h4 {
   display: inline;
}
```

HTML:

```
<td class="thread-title thread-column">
    <h4>Some long text here to be truncated</h4>
    <a href="http://www.google.com" title="Go to article" target="_blank"> my link </a>
</td>
```

Comment: Just to be clear, you want this truncate style to work in a table?

Comment: Yes, at this moment it works in a table, but I want only the h4 text to be truncated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach that might work in a HTML table.

I set `display: inline-block` to both the `h4` and the `a` elements and applied a `max-width` value to `h4`.

A constraining width or max-width needs to be set to `h4` for the ellipsis to take effect.

If you want to constrain the width of both `h4` and `a`, that is trickier and would take more HTML mark-up or JavaScript (you can make a decision based on your design requirements).

Remember to set the `h4` margins to zero (or as needed) and use vertical-align to keep the two elements lined up properly.

To be sure that the `h4` and `a` stay on a single line, wrap them in a `div` with `white-space: nowrap` (this may not be strictly needed depending on your layout).

If you use `white-space: nowrap` on the wrapping div, then the `h4` element does not need that propery, so you can simplify the CSS slightly.

```css
table {
  border: 1px dotted blue;
}
h4 {
  max-width: 125px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  vertical-align: top;
}
a {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
div {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="thread-title thread-column">
      <div>
        <h4>Some long text here to be truncated</h4>
        <a href="http://www.google.com" title="Go to article" target="_blank"> my link </a>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```